# How to stop a command execution in java

Tags: java, process, command, runtime.exec

Is there a way to stop a running process using java?
I'm using this piece of code to run a command:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String.format("cmd /c %s", command));
```

Afterwards, I need to end/stop/terminate it.

Does anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: What happened when you ran this?

Comment: As a general tip:  Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [destroy()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#destroy%28%29) method in Process, which can be of use.

**public abstract void destroy()**

> Kills the subprocess. The subprocess represented by this Process
>   object is forcibly terminated.